# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'compat'

Tags: python, tensorflow, avx, python-wheel

Since my CPU doesn't support AVX instructions and I want to install a newer version of Tensorflow (>= 2.0), I installed a tensorflow wheel for my Python version from https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel using pip

However, when trying to import tensorflow, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from . _api.v2 import compat
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\compat\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import v1
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\compat\v1\__init__.py", line 664, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v1 import estimator
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1 import estimator
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\_api\v1\estimator\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1.estimator import experimental
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\_api\v1\estimator\experimental\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.dnn import dnn_logit_fn_builder
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\dnn.py", line 33, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import estimator
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 53, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import util as estimator_util
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\util.py", line 75, in <module>
    class _DatasetInitializerHook(tf.compat.v1.train.SessionRunHook):
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'compat'
```

I have searched, but not found anybody who encountered the same issue using tensorflow wheel (just trying to install tensorflow via "pip install tensorflow" isn't going to work for me, as I will run into the ImportError: DLL load failed-error).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btensorflow%5D+AttributeError%3A+module+tensorflow+has+no+attribute+compat

Comment: Thanks, but I've already been there and it didn't help me.

Comment: I don't see where I asked two questions?

Comment: The DLL load failed-error stems from the fact that my CPU doesn't support AVX (as stated at the top of my question; also explained in the link I posted). This was not intended to be the question, hence why it's just a comment in brackets.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'compat' when loading tf.compat.v1.train.SessionRunHook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62622704/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-compat-when-loading-tf-co)

Answer (score 0):

It seems tensorflow is not installed in your system in the proper way which causes this error.

You need to install tensorflow using any of the below command:

```
pip install tensorflow   
pip install tensorflow-gpu  # to install tensorflow for gpu support
pip install tensorflow==2.4.0  # to install a specific tensorflow version
```

For `Anaconda` environment in jupyter notebook, use below code:

```
conda install tensorflow
conda install tensorflow-gpu  # to install tensorflow for gpu support
```

Please follow [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) link which has step wise instructions to install tensorflow in your system.