# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'compat' when loading tf.compat.v1.train.SessionRunHook

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-wheel

I can see that this question has been asked before here
[tensorflow-has-no-attribute-compat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62022827/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-compat)

but the answer given was to

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x64)
```

It did not work for the previous member it has not worked for me either. I have visual studio 2019 installed. I downloaded it anyways and ran a repair of (MV C++) just in case. Still getting same error.

So that being said I have not found a valid solution for this anywhere on google or stackoverflow.
Here are some spec details of what I have installed.

```
tensorflow-gpu 2.1
python 3.7.7
CUDA 10.1
Anaconda 3.7
```

Looks like gpu started successfully.

```
2020-06-28 07:19:47.851257: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
```

python packages for 3.7.7.
All packages installed via pip. Only tensorflow installed via conda. Dont think it makes a difference. I used conda so I can specify install version 2.1, pip would automatically install 2.2.

```
Package                Version
---------------------- ----------------------------
absl-py                0.9.0
appdirs                1.4.4
astor                  0.7.1
astroid                2.4.2
astropy                4.0.1.post1
attrs                  19.3.0
backcall               0.2.0
bayesian-optimization  1.2.0
black                  19.10b0
bleach                 3.1.5
blinker                1.4
brotlipy               0.7.0
cachetools             4.1.0
certifi                2020.6.20
cffi                   1.14.0
chardet                3.0.4
click                  7.1.2
cloudpickle            1.3.0
colorama               0.4.3
confuse                1.3.0
cryptography           2.9.2
cycler                 0.10.0
decorator              4.4.2
defusedxml             0.6.0
entrypoints            0.3
future                 0.18.2
gast                   0.2.2
gitdb                  4.0.5
GitPython              3.1.3
google-auth            1.17.2
google-auth-oauthlib   0.4.1
google-pasta           0.2.0
grpcio                 1.27.2
gym                    0.17.2
h2o                    3.30.0.5
h5py                   2.10.0
htmlmin                0.1.12
idna                   2.10
ImageHash              4.1.0
importlib-metadata     1.7.0
invoke                 1.4.1
ipykernel              5.3.0
ipython                7.16.1
ipython-genutils       0.2.0
ipywidgets             7.5.1
isort                  4.3.21
jedi                   0.17.1
Jinja2                 2.11.2
joblib                 0.15.1
json5                  0.9.5
jsonschema             3.2.0
jupyter                1.0.0
jupyter-client         6.1.3
jupyter-console        6.1.0
jupyter-core           4.6.3
jupyterlab             2.1.5
jupyterlab-server      1.1.5
kaggle                 1.5.6
Keras                  2.4.3
Keras-Applications     1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing    1.1.0
kiwisolver             1.2.0
lazy-object-proxy      1.4.3
lightgbm               2.3.1
llvmlite               0.33.0
Markdown               3.2.2
MarkupSafe             1.1.1
matplotlib             3.2.2
mccabe                 0.6.1
missingno              0.4.2
mistune                0.8.4
mkl-service            2.3.0
nbconvert              5.6.1
nbdime                 2.0.0
nbformat               5.0.7
networkx               2.4
notebook               6.0.3
numba                  0.50.1
numpy                  1.19.0
oauthlib               3.0.1
opt-einsum             0+untagged.56.g2664021.dirty
packaging              20.4
pandas                 1.0.5
pandas-profiling       2.8.0
pandocfilters          1.4.2
parso                  0.7.0
path                   13.1.0
path.py                12.4.0
pathspec               0.8.0
patsy                  0.5.1
phik                   0.10.0
pickleshare            0.7.5
Pillow                 7.1.2
pip                    20.1.1
plotly                 4.8.2
prometheus-client      0.8.0
prompt-toolkit         3.0.5
protobuf               3.12.3
py4j                   0.10.9
pyasn1                 0.4.8
pyasn1-modules         0.2.7
pycparser              2.20
pyglet                 1.5.0
Pygments               2.6.1
PyJWT                  1.7.1
pylint                 2.5.3
pyOpenSSL              19.1.0
pyparsing              2.4.7
pyreadline             2.1
pyrsistent             0.16.0
PySocks                1.7.1
pyspark                3.0.0
python-dateutil        2.8.1
python-slugify         4.0.0
pytz                   2020.1
PyWavelets             1.1.1
pywin32                228
pywinpty               0.5.7
PyYAML                 5.3.1
pyzmq                  19.0.1
qtconsole              4.7.5
QtPy                   1.9.0
regex                  2020.6.8
requests               2.24.0
requests-oauthlib      1.2.0
retrying               1.3.3
rsa                    4.6
scikit-learn           0.23.1
scipy                  1.5.0
seaborn                0.10.1
Send2Trash             1.5.0
setuptools             47.3.1.post20200616
six                    1.15.0
smmap                  3.0.4
statsmodels            0.11.1
tabulate               0.8.7
tangled-up-in-unicode  0.0.6
tensorboard            2.2.2
tensorboard-plugin-wit 1.6.0.post3
tensorflow             2.1.0
tensorflow-estimator   2.2.0
termcolor              1.1.0
terminado              0.8.3
testpath               0.4.4
text-unidecode         1.3
threadpoolctl          2.1.0
toml                   0.10.1
tornado                6.0.4
tqdm                   4.46.1
traitlets              4.3.3
typed-ast              1.4.1
urllib3                1.24.3
visions                0.4.4
wcwidth                0.2.5
webencodings           0.5.1
Werkzeug               0.16.1
wheel                  0.34.2
widgetsnbextension     3.5.1
win-inet-pton          1.1.0
wincertstore           0.2
wrapt                  1.12.1
zipp                   3.1.0
```

This is the error I get once i try to import tensorflow. (NOTE: I get this error on GPU install and CPU install of Tensorflow 2.1)

```
    Python 3.7.7 (default, May  6 2020, 11:45:54) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
2020-07-05 09:48:26.577683: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "G:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda37\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "G:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda37\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    from . _api.v2 import compat
  File "G:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda37\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\compat\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from . import v1
  File "G:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda37\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\compat\v1\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from . import compat
  File "G:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda37\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\compat\v1\compat\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from . import v1
  File "G:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda37\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\compat\v1\compat\v1\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1 import app
  File "G:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda37\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\compat\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from . import v1
  File "G:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda37\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\compat\v1\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from . import compat
  File "G:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda37\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\compat\v1\compat\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from . import v1
  File "G:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda37\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\compat\v1\compat\v1\__init__.py", line 667, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v1 import estimator
  File "G:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda37\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1 import estimator
  File "G:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda37\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\_api\v1\estimator\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1.estimator import experimental
  File "G:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda37\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\_api\v1\estimator\experimental\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.dnn import dnn_logit_fn_builder
  File "G:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda37\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\dnn.py", line 33, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import estimator
  File "G:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda37\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 53, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import util as estimator_util
  File "G:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda37\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\util.py", line 75, in <module>
    class _DatasetInitializerHook(tf.compat.v1.train.SessionRunHook):
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'compat'
```

Comment: I face the same issue. Did you solve the issue ? How

Comment: No.. I still dont have a solution. I have been working on this for 3 weeks. I saved the env and moved on I need to catchup on other work. I tried Docker and within docker I got the same error, FYI.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is usually caused by the broken TensorFlow-estimator module.

simply do a

```
pip install tensorflow-estimator==2.1.*
```

Comment: after running test still looks like some issues exists

Comment: ERROR: tensorflow 2.1.0 has requirement opt-einsum>=2.3.2, but you'll have opt-einsum 0+untagged.56.g2664021.dirty which is incompatible.
ERROR: tensorflow 2.1.0 has requirement scipy==1.4.1; python_version >= "3", but you'll have scipy 1.5.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: tensorflow 2.1.0 has requirement tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0, but you'll have tensorboard 2.2.2 which is incompatible.

Comment: @LeoTorres u need to downgrade these packages will be better to create a new environment and then do a `pip install tensorflow-estimator==2.1.0` and then `pip install tensorflow==2.1.0`

Comment: This solution by Inder is the answer once I ran the fix the issue was fixed Athi i hope this solution helps you. The problem is version. You have all your version in line. I  learned that the hard way.

Answer (score 17):

**Special note for Conda users**:

When one enters `conda install tensorflow` it installs **2.1.0** but it brings with it **tensorflow-estimator 2.2.0**. To fix this problem simply run `conda install tensorflow-estimator==2.1.0` after installing tensorflow 2.1.0 in Conda.

This advice is valid until conda switches to TF 2.2.0 (or better yet to 2.3.0)

credits to [this TF github thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40422)

UPDATE: as of 20-Aug-2021 Conda has TF 2.4 for Windows and 2.5 for Linux. Check [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow-gpu) to see current state of TF support in Conda.

Answer (score 4):

the specs you have given are correct

tensorflow-gpu 2.1

python 3.7.7

CUDA 10.1

Anaconda 3.7

but in tensorflow 2.X
first install

```
pip install tensorflow-estimator==2.1.*
```

then install

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

and then run the following command to check the number of gpu

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

Comment: I was able to make conda work, but I like the command for checking that it was there.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution worked for me. [Reference](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/37525#issuecomment-670926083)

First install Estimator=2.1 then the rest:

```
conda remove tensorflow
conda install tensorflow-estimator 2.1
conda install tensorflow-gpu=2.1
```