# Tensorflow error - cannot find attribute '__internal__'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

A week ago, my Notebook in Google Colaboratory was working fine after installing the following libraries:

```
!pip install te
!pip install tensorflow==2.1
!pip install keras==2.3.1

!pip install -U segmentation-models
!pip install -U --pre segmentation-models
```

These are the versions of the libraries I need to work. 7 days later I try to start my Notebook again in Colab, with the same versions of libraries and me on import
import segmentation_models as sm

> Gives an error message: 48 LOCAL.ALL_OBJECTS = {} ---> 49
> LOCAL.GENERATED_WITH_V2 = tf.internal.tf2.enabled() 50 51 #
> Compatibility aliases (need to exist in both V1 and V2).
>
> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.compat.v2' has no attribute
> 'internal'

The same laptop, the same libraries! How is this possible, I don’t understand?

Tried doing:

```
   !pip uninstall tensorflow
    !pip uninstall tensorflow-estimator
    !pip install tensorflow-estimator==2.1.0
```

As suggested here [AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'compat' when loading tf.compat.v1.train.SessionRunHook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62622704/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-compat-when-loading-tf-co)

Tried:

```
!pip install tensorflow-estimator==2.1.0
!pip install tensorflow==2.1.0
```

It did not help

Comment: @M.Innat, not all. Now when I try to import ```from keras.utils import normalize```  get an error ```AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.compat.v2' has no attribute '__internal__'```

Comment: it should be `from tensorflow.keras.utils import ... whatever`

Comment: don't mix new `tf.keras` and old `keras` in same imports.

Comment: @M.Innat, thank you so much! Please fill out in response